# Mail the link of question which I have favorited

Tags: feature-request

I think it is better to mail the link of questions which belongs to the tag that I had favorited, with subject as the title of question. It will help me to find questions in future, and can save time when sorting questions and help reduce page loading time.

Here is the mail from the Stack Overflow,

[image: subscription confirmation mail for Array tag]

But, when I click on the link it leads me to the following message,

[image]

Comment: You mean an E-Mail notification of new questions in a tag? That would likely drown you in new messages, it would hardly work. There is an E-Mail digest for every site, though - although I don't at the moment know where to switch it on

Comment: Re your edit: Oh, that looks like it might be a bug. I'll tag the question as such so the developers see it.